# $1,2,\cdots,n$ or $1,\cdots,n$?

Tags: soft-question, notation, article-writing

In mathematical writing, when should one write "$1,2,\cdots,n$" and when should one write "$1,\cdots,n$"?

It seems to me that writing $1,2,\cdots,n$ is actually wrong if $n=1$ is allowed.

When writing a paper or a thesis, should the author be consistent in the choice? That is, should he stick to one of the two expressions all the time, unless for some very good reasons to choose the other occasionally?

Comment: As long as it's clear what the author means, I don't think there's a problem.

Comment: It seems that for most cases, $1,\cdots,n$ is clear enough, yet many people still write $1,2,\cdots,n$.

Comment: I think it's really a matter of preference. You're technically right that $1, 2, \ldots, n$ is "wrong" if $n = 1$, but it's IMO still clear what is meant so there's no harm done. And $1, \ldots, n$ is "wrong" when $n=0$, but I would argue it's clear that in this case you're considering the empty set.

Comment: The other comments have addressed the main issue, but I just want to add an answer to your second question: Yes, one should be consistent.

Comment: It's better to use normal dots here, to be at the same level as the commas: $1,...,n$. Centred dots are for joining centred operators, e.g. $1+\cdots+n$.

Comment: It probably just a personal preference, but when listing things I believe you should place the dots on the baseline of the text (with the ldots macro: $\ldots$), when seeing raised dots, I always think stuff is being multiplied (as Tony said in the comment above, any centered operator could work).

Comment: You might want to be aware of dotsc (dots to be used between commas) and dotsb (dots to be used between a binary operation) and their friends, all provided by amsmath, which give a semantic alternative and which combine ldots or cdots and spacing.

Answer (score 3):

There are two two things to consider:

- clarity,
- consistency.

For example (it's my own experirnce based on reading lots of research papers):

- The *context* is the king, e.g. non-consistent formatting could be justified if you are reproducing *exactly* a formula from some other well-known paper (that is, if, for whatever reason, you are reproducing their formatting too).
- Try to keep all such enumerations either $0$-based or $1$-based, never mix the two (if necessary, add $+1$ or $-1$).
- If frequent enough, define $[n]=\{0,1,\ldots,n-1\}$ (or starting from $1$, see above).
- I prefer $1,\ldots,n$ to $1,2,\ldots,n$, because it's shorter.
- However, if there are also more complicated expressions or other sequences, like $1,2,4,\ldots,2^{n-1}$, then I write $0,1,2,\ldots,n-1$ (enough terms to avoid confusion).
- I prefer `\ldots` to `\cdots`, that is $0,1,\ldots,n-1$ to $0,1,\cdots,n-1$.
- For more complicated expressions it's beneficial to the reader to include the two last terms, e.g. $1,2,3,\ldots,n-1,n$.
- You should cover the edge cases (e.g. $n=1$) by text or an explicit formula.
- Even if there are some conventions like $\sum_{i=k}^{k-1}\operatorname{whatever}(i)=0$, which go nicely with $1,2,\ldots,n$ being an empty sequence for $n=0$, always, *always*, explain them (perhaps in the footnote if you don't want to break the thought).
- For infinite sequences include enough terms to make clear what it is, in case of more than arithmetic or geometric sequences use additional clues, e.g. text, middle term or whole formula, e.g.:

  - $0,0,\ldots$, not $0,\ldots$;
  - $1,2,3,\ldots$ if $1,2,4,\ldots$ also happens;
  - $0!, 1!, 2!, \ldots$ rather than $1,1,2,6,\ldots$;
  - $\frac{1\cdot2}{2},\frac{2\cdot3}{2},\frac{3\cdot4}{2},\ldots$ or $1,3,6,\ldots,\frac{i(i+1)}{2},\ldots$ depending on your style;
  - $f(0),f(1),f(2),\ldots$ for anything more complicated.

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$

Comment: It is very clear; thank you very much! Actually I never thought that my naive question could receive such a good answer!

Comment: Regarding `\ldots` and `\cdots`, I always figured it depended on the sympol you have between elements. I use `\ldots` if it's a list with commas between numbers $1, 2, \ldots, n$, but `\cdots` if it's a sum or product $1+2+\cdots+n$. Bassically, use the one that makes dots appear in the same height as the symbols they represent.

Comment: @Arthur For me it's a matter of taste, I would imagine `\ldots` in $1+2+\ldots+n$ is just as good and readable, same with `\cdots` in $$\left[\begin{array}{cccc}1&0&\cdots&0\\0&1& &\vdots\\\vdots& &\ddots&0\\0&\cdots&0&1\end{array}\right],$$ so I wouldn't force any option.

Answer (score 0):

1,2,⋯,n is a convention to make it clear that the list is of positive integers. The opening items in a list should make its iterative pattern reasonably clear, and the sequence should be accompanied by a verbal intension to clarify any pattern that's not obvious.

1,2,⋯,n shouldn't be wrong if n=1 is allowed, only if n=2 is not allowed.